# Remote desktop connection taking longer than 20 seconds to connect

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, remote-desktop

When connecting to one of my servers with remote desktop it takes an unusually long time to present me a log in box. After connecting server is very responsive so it doesn't seem like it is running low on resources.

- It only happens on this one server.
- Server is running Windows Server 2008r2
- The server is one of multiple hosted on a hyper-v box.
- Hyper-V manager shows that disk usage and memory usage is low.

What might be causing this delay?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what happens while you wait and how exactly your connecting to the server ?

Comment: @Stephane i connect using `mstsc` as usual. Then i get the connecting to window 'initializing remote connecting' for a long time. Then it asks for username and password like usual

Comment: Do you get the username and password promt in a MSTC dialog or do you go to the server remote console and are prompted there ? I'm asking so I can find out if you have an issue with network-level authentication

Comment: @stephane it asks in a dialog box

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was a DNS issue; trying 3 IPv6 addresses that wouldn't connect before trying a working IPv4 address.

Sorry all!

Answer (score 0):

Is the 2008 R2 server isolated from the internet? Most likely it's attempting to update its root certificates and timing out.

Try the following

1. Launch Computer Configuration
2. Go to Policies
3. Open Administrative Templates
4. Expand System
5. Explore Internet Communication Settings

Change the setting of "Turn off Automatic Root Certificates Update" to enabled

Answer (score 0):

You can enable user logon logging by following the instructions in [KB221833](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/221833).

That will create a log file in `%Systemroot%\debug\UserMode` which will contains timing information about each step of the logging process.